# Hibernate: Failed to retrieve multiple field values

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new in Hibernate. I successfully retrieve single column and complete table but when ever I am trying for a particular column in a table It gives me error.
Here is the error

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2c7d121c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@65aa6596, [Ljava.lang.Object;@67389cb8, [Ljava.lang.Object;@419a20a6
```

Here is the entity: MovieRatings.java

```
package com.hibernate.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "movie_ratings")
public class MovieRatings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private int user_id;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int movie_id;
    @Column(name = "rating")
    private int rating;

    public MovieRatings()
    {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public int getMovie_id() {
        return movie_id;
    }

    public void setMovie_id(int movie_id) {
        this.movie_id = movie_id;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MovieRatings [id=" + id + ", user_id=" + user_id + ", movie_id=" + movie_id + ", rating=" + rating
                + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is the main function

```
package com.hibernate.getdata;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.hibernate.entity.MovieRatings;;

public class GetMovieInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(MovieRatings.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            String hql="select E.user_id, E.rating from MovieRatings as E";
            System.out.println(hql);
            @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked" })           
            List<MovieRatings> theRatings = session.createQuery(hql).list();
            System.out.println(theRatings); 
            /*for(MovieRatings tempRatings:theRatings)
            {
                System.out.println(tempRatings.getUser_id());
                System.out.println(tempRatings.getRating());
            }*/
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: It is not an error but an array output.

Answer (score 2):

> I successfully retrieve single column and complete table but when
>   ever I am trying for a particular column in a table It gives me error.

With Hibernate (true also for JPA), when you select in your query specific column(s) and not the entity itself,  the `list()` method of `Query` returns an object with this structure : `List<Object[]>`.

Each element of the List corresponds to a row and each element is an array that contains the selected values in the order used by the `select`. 
So, you have to iterate on the list to retrieve the values :

```
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
 for(Object[] current : result ){
     Integer userId = (String)current[0];
     Float rating = (Float) current[1];
     .....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this :

```
try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            String hql="select E.user_id, E.rating from MovieRatings as E";
            System.out.println(hql);
            @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked" })    
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
            query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(GetMovieInfo.class));
            List<MovieRatings> theRatings = query.list();
                System.out.println(theRatings); 
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
```